# Sharing Data contract class among different services

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

I have this data contract class as a separate dll in my WCF server code:

```
namespace Engine.V100.SharedDataContract
{
    #region Authorization
    [DataContract(Namespace = "Engine.V100.SharedDataContract")]
    [Serializable]
    public class Identity
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string UserName;
        [DataMember]
        public Guid UserID;
        [DataMember]
        public string PassWord;
        [DataMember]
        public Guid GroupCode;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I referenced the same dll in client side code and I selected the option of "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies." But type Identity is still defined by each service reference separately and I have problem of conflicting assemblies.

This is the sample of what client side service reference generates:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Identity", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class Identity : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

[System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

[System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
private string UserNameField;

private System.Guid UserIDField;

[System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
private string PassWordField;

private System.Guid GroupCodeField;

[global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
    get {
        return this.extensionDataField;
    }
    set {
        this.extensionDataField = value;
    }
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false)]
public string UserName {
    get {
        return this.UserNameField;
    }
    set {
        if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.UserNameField, value) != true)) {
            this.UserNameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("UserName");
        }
    }
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true, Order=1)]
public System.Guid UserID {
    get {
        return this.UserIDField;
    }
    set {
        if ((this.UserIDField.Equals(value) != true)) {
            this.UserIDField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("UserID");
        }
    }
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=2)]
public string PassWord {
    get {
        return this.PassWordField;
    }
    set {
        if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.PassWordField, value) != true)) {
            this.PassWordField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("PassWord");
        }
    }
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true, Order=3)]
public System.Guid GroupCode {
    get {
        return this.GroupCodeField;
    }
    set {
        if ((this.GroupCodeField.Equals(value) != true)) {
            this.GroupCodeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("GroupCode");
        }
    }
}

public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
    System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
    if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
        propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

It may be considerable that referened type namespace is tempuri.
Please help

Comment: I had this problem this morning.  The only way I could get around it was to reference the dll containing the DataContract types in the client solution, rather than another project in the solution.  I'm not entirely sure why but try referencing the built dll.

Comment: Let me try it and I will update here. Thanks.